# StartIntent() not working in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a custom adapter for my list view so that I can have listener events on my checkbox and list as well. Following is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;
    private final String TAG = "MyPerformanceArrayAdapter";
    private static final int TASK_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;


    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public CheckBox reminderCheckBox;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        super(context, R.layout.reminder_row, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_row, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.reminderRowTextId);
            viewHolder.reminderCheckBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxId);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        final int pos = position;
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        String s = names[position];
        holder.text.setText(s);

        holder.reminderCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.reminderCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pos-->chkd" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pos-->un--chkd" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEXT CLICKED" + pos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ReminderModificationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, pos);
                Log.i(TAG, "row clickd --> " + pos);
                startActivity(intent,ACTIVITY_EDIT); <<<<-------ERROR ON THIS LINE
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting on pointed line (startActivity(intent,ACTIVITY_EDIT);) is:

> The method startActivity(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Can anyone please provide some pointers for same?

Comment: you must use context.startActivity(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is in the View.OnClickListener, the wrong context is being used. You need to call  startActivity() on the Activity class and not on the View.OnClickListener class.

To do this you should be able to do:

`context.startActivity(intent, ACTIVITY_EDIT);`

or

`((Activity) context).startActivity(intent, ACTIVITY_EDIT);`

Comment: Would be awesome if you accepted it as an answer if it worked ;)

Comment: actually there is some minimum time before which we can accept.so was waiting fr that.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomAdapter.this.getContext().startActivity()` instead.

Why:

To refer outer instance from inner anonymous class use `OuterClassName.this` . In your case `CustomAdapter.this`.

And, to start activity, you need `Context`, which you can get by calling `getContext()` method of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent mintent = new Intent(context,ReminderModificationActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(mintent);
```